# How to create Adobe Air application that pulls images from a folder on computer outside of application

Tags: javascript, html, air

I am building a simple HTML/javascript  Adobe Air Application that will be installed on a desktop computer. The application will just have thumb nails of movies and when clicked the movie pops up and plays. The thumbnails and the movies will be pulled from a folder named images with a loop. The user needs to be able to add thumbnails and movies to the folder as needed.

Is there a way to do this?

If I add the images folder in the application there is no way for the user to access it when he installs it on his computer. Is there a way to have the application create a folder on the clients computer that is accessible for him to add thumbnails and movies?

Or is there a completely better way to approach this?

The image tag looks something like this

img src="../images/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="../images/1.jpg" class="thumb"

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create folders and files. Use the File.documentsDirectory to get the path to user's documents directory and then create your subfolders there. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/filesystem/File.html for more information on the File class in AIR.